# How to create dropdownlist in mvc3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created one mvc3 application.

There is one form where i'm taking values from user.

There is one field called `Gender`

i want to give a dropdown list for that with values `Male` and `Female`

but i dont understand where and how i specify there values please help.

I need an Ajax Helper method for this or any asynchronous script

Comment: First result on google http://www.aspnetmvcninja.com/general/asp-net-mvc-dropdown-list-example

Comment: yes i have tried but problem is i need to select that from dropdown list and once it is selected I'm changing radio button values but i need all these as asynchronously

Comment: Post a code example, you talk about changing a radio button, include that please.

Comment: Tell me what I'm missing in my DDL tutorials and I'll add it.   [1]: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc
  [2]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Wouldn't radio be better for M/F?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way is to do this in Html :

```
 <select id="selection" name="selection">
     <option value="1">Male</option>
     <option value="2">Female</option>
 </select>
```

You can also do this with razor :

```
 @Html.DropDownLiwt("GenderSelection", "Male")
```

after having done this inside the controler :

```
 Dim genderSelection As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
 genderSelection.Add("Male")
 genderSelection.Add("Female")

 ViewData("GenderSelection") = New SelectList(genderSelection)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create Entity class for your dropdown. It will return a list of value

```
public class KeyValueEntity
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

public class MyViewModel
    {
        public List<KeyValueEntity> Status { get; set; }
}
```

On your controller write the following code

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Dropdown()
        {  
                MyViewModel model = GetDefaultModel();  
                return View(model);
            }
        }


public MyViewModel GetDefaultModel()
        {
            var entity = new MyViewModel();            
            entity.Status = GetMyDropdownValues();            
            return entity;
        }


private List<KeyValueEntity> GetMyDropdownValues()
        {
            return new List<KeyValueEntity>
            {
                new KeyValueEntity { Description = "Yes" , Value ="1" },
                new KeyValueEntity { Description = "No" , Value ="0"}
            };
        }
```

Code for your cshtml page : Now you need to bind your view with your model for this on top of your view you define your model class

```
@model MyViewModel
Following is the code for dropdown binding

 @Html.LabelForModel("Status:")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, new SelectList(Model.Status, "Value", "Description"), "-- Please Select --")
```